# Pac-man clone movement in java

Tags: java

[image: PacMan]

I want to use rectangle to detect collision horizontal and vertical pac-man and wall. Because i want if detect horizontal collision pac-man can only move left or right and reverse with vertical. My idea is make rectangle like this:

```
public void checkMap() {
    int xRaw = pac.getX();
    int yRaw = pac.getY();
    rectanglePacX = new Rectangle(xRaw+1, yRaw, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE);
    rectanglePacX1 = new Rectangle(xRaw-1, yRaw, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE);
    rectanglePacY = new Rectangle(xRaw, yRaw+1, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE);
    rectanglePacY1 = new Rectangle(xRaw, yRaw-1, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (isPacCollisionWallz(items.get(i), rectanglePacX) && isPacCollisionWallz(items.get(i), rectanglePacX1)) {
            vector = 1;
        }
        if (isPacCollisionWallz(items.get(i), rectanglePacY) && isPacCollisionWallz(items.get(i), rectanglePacY1)) {
            vector = 2;
        } else {
            vector = 3;
        }
    }

}
```

and here's my method `isPacCollisionWallz()`:

```
private boolean isPacCollisionWallz(MapItem mapItem, Rectangle rectangle) {
    return rectangle.intersects(mapItem.getRectangle());
}
```

When `vector == 1` I enable the character move up or down, `vector == 2` move left or right, `vector == 3` in the crossroad it can move all directions. But I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Don't try to implements logic like this directly in the GUI; PACMAN is just a board game (can be reproduced in an `Cell[][]`) where you move in 4directions. Create the model, the board and the movement. Then add the view on it. And for the rest, not sure what is the question.

Comment: i want to use rectangle to detect collision horizontal and vertical pacman and wall.Because i want if detect horizontal collision pac-man can only move left or right and same with vertical.Sorry for my english i hope you can understand.

Comment: Like I said, don't use `Rectangle` to detect anything. Create the logic using arrays. It would be as simple as `cellUp().getType().isWall()` ... Then add the GUI you have using the arrays of cell you are using to control the game. See about mvc

Comment: Are you taking into account the possibility of pacman being able to move up but not down, or right but not left for example? You should use a set or something to accumulate the possible directions each turn IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you create those rectangle are incorrect for :

```
rectanglePacX1 = new Rectangle(xRaw-1, yRaw, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE); 
rectanglePacY1 = new Rectangle(xRaw, yRaw-1, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE);
```

You get one pixel back and set the size with `Pac.SIZE`. It will give a rectangle just 1 pixel off with the current one. What you need is :

```
rectanglePacX1 = new Rectangle(xRaw - Pac.SIZE -1, yRaw, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE); 
rectanglePacY1 = new Rectangle(xRaw, yRaw - Pac.SIZE- 1, Pac.SIZE, Pac.SIZE);
```

An image is a bit more simple to explain the problem

[image]

In red is the rectangle you create substracting 1 pixel, in green is what you want, substracting 1 pixel AND the size of the rectangle itself.

---

Note: I need to tell that this is not a good pratice to implements logic in the view. It is better to implement the game itself in OOP then add a view on the logic, using an [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is generally own I do. See what is [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Implement a class `Board` that contains an 2 dimension array of `Cell`, each cell will have a type (have a coin, is a wall, ...). That will allow you `PacMan` instance to be able to detect the movement easily.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse your **game model** with What you see on the screen. The model can be a simple representation of the game map, which could be as simple as a grid of cells:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x ...>  x    x
x xxxxx xxxx x
x     x      x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You can represent that in Java as an object (call it `Maze`, because `Map` means something else in Java) which contains a grid of cells. Define a `Cell` class:

```
public class Cell {
    public boolean isWall() { ... }
    ...
}
```

and a `Maze` class:

```
public class Maze {
    private Cell[][] cells;
    ...
    public Cell getCellAt( int x, int y ) { ... }
}
```

The when you want to display the maze on the screen you can just consult the maze object to work out which cells contain walls, or ghosts or whatever, and render that to the screen.

The advantage of this is that **collision-detection becomes super-easy**: just get the cell which is left/right/above/below the position of the player, and call `isWall()` to determine whether you can move there.

It also means that that part of your code becomes decoupled from the details of how you draw the game: it doesn't need to know about things like `Pac.SIZE` or what colour your walls are.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest

Comment: Definitly the way to go. An enum for the type of cell and you don't have those problems.  (Didn't want to provide to much of that part to let OP do it, there is so many examples...). I personnaly prefer to not uses array, but `Cell` that knows the neighbours. It allows some interesting behavior like "infinite" generated board.